# How to extract the index of an array with the most value -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am trying to create a ranking from the values of an array.

```
let united = prompt('vote ManUnited from 0 to 5')
let city = prompt('vote ManCity from 0 to 5')
let arsenal = prompt('vote arsenal from 0 to 5')
let chelsea = prompt('vote chelsea from 0 to 5')

let ranking = [united,arsenal,city,chelsea]
```

I would like to take the index of teams with the most value. For example we have two teams with the same value:

```
ranking = [5,2,5,2]
```

I want to create this hypothetical situation:

```
console.log('congrats ' + team1 + 'and' + team2 + ' you are first in the rankings on equal points!')
```

where the team1 and team2 are in this example: *city, united*

Comment: Highest value of an Array? `let max = Math.max(...ranking);`. Question is unclear.

Comment: Doesn't `prompt` return a string?

Comment: You could use `Math.max.apply(this, ['5','2','5','2'])` to get the max value, and then use that max value to turn around and find all the indexes.

Comment: `let maxIndex = ranking.indexOf(Math.max(...ranking).toString());`

Comment: @StackSlave OP wants to compare if the first and second value are equal.

Comment: @Alex, question is unclear to me. If that's the case use `.slice` or `.splice` depending on needs... or just don't use that a `ranking` Array at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

- I have reassigned your array to an array of objects, to store in addition to the value also the name of the club.
  *If* you store only the value you can not print out the corresponding club name and your output would look like this:
  `congrats 5 and 4 you are first in the rankings on equal points!`
- Also because `prompt()` returns a string I *parse* this return value to an integer.

### Solution

- Sort the rankings objects based on its values from the highest value to the lowest.(**descending order**)
- Then check if in the sorted array the first and second object have the same voting value.
  -> If yes then print out the string
  -> If not do whatever.
- If you want to compare if three elments equal
  `ranking[0].value === ranking[1].value && ranking[0].value == ranking[2].value`

```js
let united = parseInt(prompt('vote ManUnited from 0 to 5'));
let city = parseInt(prompt('vote ManCity from 0 to 5'));
let arsenal = parseInt(prompt('vote arsenal from 0 to 5'));
let chelsea = parseInt(prompt('vote chelsea from 0 to 5'));

let ranking = [{name:"united", value:united}, {name:"city", value:city}, {name:"arsenal", value:arsenal}, {name:"chelsea", value:chelsea}]

ranking.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.value - a.value;
});
if(ranking[0].value === ranking[1].value){
console.log('congrats ' + ranking[0].name + ' and ' + ranking[1].name + ' you are first in the rankings on equal points!')
}else{
  console.log("Whatever");
}
```

Comment: sorry @alex, if i have all 4 or 3 teams team with the same value and want to print: 'all teams are equa!","united, city and arsenal are equal!"?

Comment: check if(ranking[0]. value === ranking[1].value && ranking[0].value ===ranking[2].value 
If the first and the second are equal and the first and the third this implicates that the second and the third also equal.
The same applies to 4 elements

Answer (score -1):

```
*you can do something like adding up all array values like*

      united = {1, 5, 2, 0, 1}
      city = {2, 0, 3, 4, 0}
      arsenal = {5, 2, 1, 0, 2}

  *at end united final score will be 1+5+2+0+1 = 10
  and city final score will be 2+0+3+4+0 = 9 
  and arsenal will be = 10*

 **now u can use for loop to check which is highest** 
 

     for(i=0;i<3;i++){
       if(unitedTotal > cityTotal)
        {
           if(unitedTotal > arsenalTotal)
             {
               print united has won 
            }
            else if (arsenalTotal > city)
            {
              print arsenal has won
            }
        }
          else if (cityTotal > arsenalTotal)
                print city won 
       else if (arsenalTotal == unitedTotal)
              print arsenal and united both won 
    }
```